# CSS and JS file not loading while deploying war file on apache tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

was using the spring-boot-starter-web-mvc for initial development.When I deploy the war file on the server it is not loading css and js files, but when I run the same code using spring boot, it is working fine. Below is the directory structure and configuration loading the js and css file. Can anyone please let me know how to what is the problem ? Using only java based configuration for project. I have referred 8.1.1 in the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) before deploying the project and used the same pom file configuration as below.

[image: Directory structure]

Configuration file -

```
public class ViewWebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // configuration for assets/ static files
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource rb = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rb.setBasenames(new String[] { "validation" });
        return rb;
    }

}
```

pom.xml file

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j.version>2.7</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency for rendering jsp pages  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.23</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.23</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.23</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependency for rendering jsp pages  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Loading the js and css using spring-tags as below -

```
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<spring:url value="/resources/assets/js/custom.min.js" var="customJS" />
<script src="${customJS}"></script>

<link href="${customFieldAgent}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<spring:url value="/resources/assets/css/customfieldAgent.css" var="customFieldAgent" />
```

Below is the server log -

> 17:03:10.014 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
>   - Did not find handler method for [/${starrrJS}] 17:03:10.014 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for
>   HTTP request with URI [/ui/$%7BstarrrJS%7D] in DispatcherServlet with
>   name 'dispatcher' 17:03:10.014 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully
>   completed request 17:03:10.018 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet
>   with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for
>   [/ui/$%7BcustomJS%7D] 17:03:10.018 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
>   - Looking up handler method for path /${customJS} 17:03:10.019 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
>   - Did not find handler method for [/${customJS}] 17:03:10.019 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for
>   HTTP request with URI [/ui/$%7BcustomJS%7D] in DispatcherServlet with
>   name 'dispatcher' 17:03:10.019 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully
>   completed request

Comment: https://github.com/MFaisalHyder/REST_API kindly check this project and see if this helps then i will post answer if not sorted out

Comment: look you are providing (/resources/) in locations, while there is another directory /assets/ , resting above actual resource folders.
 registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**/*").addResourceLocations("/resources/assets/"); try it and let me know if it works or not

Comment: No it is not working. Have updated with server log.

Comment: Have tried many ways, used "c:url", normal convention but still not working.

Comment: Please see the dorectory structure in my poject. Move your resourcers folder in WEB-INF\resources\css, js, img , also remove extra head folder asset

Comment: I have done the same way, but it is not working.

Comment: i am posting complete proper answer which worked for me, i really hope that helps.

Comment: ok, thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it is working for me.

**Project Structure:**

```
src/main/webapp/static/[css,js,images]
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/[for all .jsp pages]
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "parent package name where all packages reside")
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // when static resources are inside resources folder under WEB-INF
        // registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");

        // when static resources are inside static folder under webapp
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }
}
```

Let **DispatcherServlet** know how to pack things up...

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ApplicationConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }     
}
```

Now call these on view like...

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/application.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    </head>
```

**Add this in your pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I will check.

Answer (score 0):

In my Spring Boot project,i tried to deploy as WAR file into TOMCAT,but it does not recognize the resource path,it throws **404 File not found error**,But when i run as SpringBootApplication,it works properly,issue only when deploy as a WAR file into TOMCAT. so finally i revealed the issue now it works perfectly on my project structure [image]

adding those lines into **application.properties** file

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=true
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/
```

i got from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

it works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

for this js,images,css or from outside of the war file images or any file can be shown and also get access by using 
this below line is common to two scenarios

spring.resources.add-mappings=true

For in the spring boot war file or any file of spring to get accessed or shown this u have to put in application.properties file or any property file

spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/

For external access file or showing external files of images u may put as

spring.resources.static-locations=file:///C:/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx

AS said vignesh R it was working great try it